# angularjs provider service injection error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I tried many ways,but it still report module injection error as:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr],it confused me for few days.
There are my source code:

service.js

```
angular.module("customServices", ["ngCookies"])
.provider("cookieChk", ($cookies) => {
    var k = 0;
    return {
        check: () => {
            if (angular.isUndefined($cookies.get("username"))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },
        $add: () => {
            k++;
            return k;
        }
    };
});
```

index.html

```
angular.module("app", ["productfinder", "ngRoute", "customServices"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, cookieChkProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $routeProvider.when("/productlist",
            {
                templateUrl: "../webui/product/productlist.html"
            })
            .when("/product/edit",
            {
                templateUrl: "../webui/product/edit.html"
            }).when("/productmanager",
            {
                templateUrl: "../webui/product/productlist.html"
            })
            .when("/about",
                {
                    templateUrl:"../webui/about.html"
                })
            .otherwise(
            {
                templateUrl: "../webui/findproduct.html",
                controller: "productfinderCtrl"
            });
    })
    .controller("mainCtrl",
    function ($scope, $http) {
        //$scope.result = cookieService.add();
    })
```

if i remove the injection parameter "customServices" from the parameter array ,it works. That is the problem, but it seem that there are no mistakes in my code, what's wrong with it? Moreover,current Angular version is the latest 1.7.0.

Comment: What you have there is a factory, not a provider. Read the documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers. I don't really get the point of injecting cookieChkProvider anyway, since you don't use it.

Comment: I assume your ultimate goal is to check for a cookie within a route provider. Do it within a **resolve**, where you can inject your service/provider (without config). Write it as: `.when("/.../...", { templateUrl: "...", resolve: cookieResolver: function(cookieChk) { return cookieChk.check(); } })`. Then it can be acquired in a controller after injecting `cookieResolver`.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks a lot, you really help me, I didn’t get clear of the difference between factory and provider

Comment: @Biao `.provider()` is only necessary if you need to configure the service in a `.config()` block. If the service you are adding doesn't need to be configured at startup, then the `.provider()` recipe doesn't provide any value over a `.service()` or `.factory()`.